# SQL Server Geography STGeomFromWKB error - System.FormatException: 24201

Tags: sql-server-2008, coordinates, geo, sqlgeography

In SQL Server 2008 R2, we have a table with a field of data type `geography`.  When queried with

```
SELECT rowid,GeoCoor,
GeoCoor.STSrid as SRID,
GeoCoor.Lat as Lat,
GeoCoor.Long as Long
FROM dbo.Locations
```

we get rows like this:

```
╔═══════╦════════════════════════════════════════════════╦══════╦══════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ rowid ║                    GeoCoor                     ║ SRID ║       Lat        ║       Long        ║
╠═══════╬════════════════════════════════════════════════╬══════╬══════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║  1092 ║ 0xE6100000010C82C540E751804240BA86EFD400B45BC0 ║ 4326 ║ 37.0024994913356 ║ -110.812550767815 ║
╚═══════╩════════════════════════════════════════════════╩══════╩══════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

All of our data are points, not lines or polygons, and we are using SRID 4326.

I am trying to UPDATE the GeoCoor field of a record with the binary value of another geographic point stored in the table.  Here is my code:

```
DECLARE @coor1 geography
SET @coor1 = geography::STGeomFromWKB(0xE6100000010C82C540E751804240BA86EFD400B45BC0,4326)

UPDATE dbo.Locations
SET GeoCoor = @coor1
WHERE RowID = 2657
```

However, the `SET @coor1 =` statement triggers an error in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography": 
System.FormatException: 24201: Latitude values must be between -90 and 90 degrees.
System.FormatException: 
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.GeographyValidator.ValidatePoint(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.Validator.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.ForwardingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.CoordinateReversingGeoDataSink.BeginFigure(Double x, Double y, Nullable`1 z, Nullable`1 m)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWkbReader.ReadFirstPoint(ByteOrder byteOrder)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWkbReader.ParseWkbPointWithoutHeader(ByteOrder byteOrder)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.OpenGisWkbReader.Read(OpenGisType type, Int32 srid)
    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromBinary(OpenGisType type, SqlBytes binary, Int32 srid)
```

Based on the initial query results, you can plainly see that the Latitude of 37.002499... is indeed between -90 and 90.  It is the Longitude that is not between -90 and 90.

I believe this is a .NET bug in the `geography::STGeomFromWKB` method, that is incorrectly transposing the Lat and Long from the WKB data (or perhaps the `.Lat` and `.Long` methods are in error?!).  My questions are:

- Can anyone tell me if I'm overlooking something, or should I go ahead and submit this to [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer)?
- Can someone reproduce this bug in a later version of SQL Server (2016)? or has it been fixed?

Answer (score 1):

After perusing other sites I thought to reverse the order of my Lat/Long.  That seemed to work.

```
SELECT  Geography::Point(Latitude,Longitude, 4326) as c
FROM na.MyTable
where Latitude  Is Not Null
```

That generates the spatial data I am looking for (but of course something else is broken) :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please indent your code with 4 spaces so that it is displayed as code and the syntax is highlightened. Best regards.